# -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have two xml file and I pars them correctly everything is in my log, I want to connect my buttons label to my xml array but I have this error

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** - 
  [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

 *** First throw call stack:

 (0x1c9b012 0x10d8e7e 0x1c3d0b4 0x30b0 0x101817 0x101882 0x50a25 0x50dbf 0x50f55 0x59f67
  0x1dfcc 0x1efab 0x30315 0x3124b 0x22cf8 0x1bf6df9 0x1c1ef3f 0x1c1e96f 0x1c41734  
 0x1c40f44 0x1c40e1b 0x1e7da 0x2065c 0x26dd 0x2605)

  libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    pLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    Presentation *p1 = [appDelegate.presentationArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"p1 %@", p1);
    pLabel.text = p1.pLabel;

    p2Label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    //I have error in this line objectAtIndex:1

    Presentation *p2 = [appDelegate.presentationArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"p2 %@", p2);
    p2Label.text = p2.pLabel;


    [yBtn setTag:0];
    [dBtn setTag:1];

}
```

Here is pasring part in appDelega :  http://pastebin.com/SygRZAGj

Here is XMLParser Class: http://pastebin.com/yuFNnFB7

Would you please help me to implement this, how can I have all file in same array , I the problem is because of empty array but how should I and How should I fixed this problem

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I want to initialize it only once, and then add eache presentation object one after the other in the same array, How can I do that

Comment: check how many elements presentationArray actually contains, from the error follows it has only 1 element, while you try to access 2nd one.

Comment: Reading your follow-up questions makes me wonder...who gave you the code you've posted so far?

Comment: Yes, your edits work. Can you please stop vandalizing your questions?

Comment: @BoltClock no I don"t want to post anything here I just want to delete

Comment: @BoltClock I don"t want to be in this forum anymore

Comment: @BoltClock and don"t want to have post here

Comment: Vandalizing your questions is *not* the way to do it. If anything you should at least give credit to the users who have helped you while you were here. If you want your user profile deleted, go here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-deletion Please do not vandalize your posts any longer.

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
app.presentationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

...creates a new array for every element you find.  Create the array once, before you start parsing, and then add presentation elements when you find them.

Comment: As I said, create it before you start parsing.  Put it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` as `self.presentationArray = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when the loop is repeating for serching the element its going to nil the object so it will have only one object at the end.